# using VBA get list item from sharepoint

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-online

I am using this and try to get sharepoint list items by using VBA in excel but I got error that 401: UNAUTHORIZED. Anyone please help me this ? thank you

```vb
Dim webUrl, wsdl, action, soap ', xhr As XMLHTTP60

Dim xhr As Object
   
 itemId = 397477
   
 LISTNAME = "Example"
   
 webUrl = "http://servername"   'set to SharePoint site url
  
  wsdl = "/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx"
  
  action = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListItems"

soap = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>" & _

"<soap:Envelope " & _  
  "xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" " & _  
  "xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" " & _   
 "xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">" & _  
  "<soap:Body>" & _  
      "<GetListItems xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"">" & _  
      "<listName>" & LISTNAME & "</listName>" & _  
      "<query><Query>" & _
           "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=""ID""/><Value Type=""Integer"">" & itemId & "</Value></Eq></Where>" &_      
      "</Query></query>" & _      
      "<viewFields><ViewFields/></viewFields>" & _     
   "</GetListItems>" & _  
  "</soap:Body>" & _
"</soap:Envelope>"

   
 Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0") 
 xhr.Open "POST", webUrl & wsdl, False   
 xhr.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"   
 xhr.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", action   
 xhr.Send soap

  MsgBox xhr.Status & ":" & xhr.statusText & vbCrLf & xhr.responseText
```

Comment: Missing authentication headers?

Comment: I tried this header to get from sharepoint online :     xhr.Open "POST", webUrl & wsdl, False, UserName, Password   But it does not work . please help